# select datetime64 columns in pandas and return that columns as series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

# create a range of dates
dates = pd.date_range('2015-01-25', periods=5, freq='W')

# create a dataframe with the dates and an additional numeric column
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': dates,
    'Value': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
})

# print the dataframe
print(dataframe)
```

Want to select a column which returns a series

```
dataframe['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dataframe['Date'])
print(dataframe['Date'])
```

```
Returns: 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
0     2015-01-25
1     2015-02-01
2     2015-02-08
3     2015-02-15
4     2015-02-22
         ...    
161   2018-02-25
162   2018-03-04
163   2018-03-11
164   2018-03-18
165   2018-03-25
```

This works but I want in other way (Without mentioning column Name)

```
date_cols = dataframe.loc[:, dataframe.dtypes == 'datetime64[ns]']
print(date_cols)
```

This Outputs: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

```
          Date
0   2015-01-25
1   2015-02-01
2   2015-02-08
3   2015-02-15
4   2015-02-22
..         ...
161 2018-02-25
162 2018-03-04
163 2018-03-11
164 2018-03-18
165 2018-03-25
```

And this returns a class object, but I'm want it as pandas series as last one like 'pandas.core.series.Series' . Is that actually possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you access the series by the column name?

Comment: try ```date_cols = dataframe.loc[:, dataframe.dtypes == 'datetime64[ns]'].squeeze()```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Method 1: Converting a single-column DataFrame to a Series

As one of the comments mentioned, you can use the [`.squeeze()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html) method on the extracted column. As mentioned in the documentation:

> Squeeze 1 dimensional axis objects into scalars[...] **DataFrames with a single column or a single row are squeezed to a Series.**

Use this method if you know that the column you want to extract is the only one that meets the selection criteria.

Since you want to select the column by type, simply use [`.select_dtypes()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```py
# Select the column(s) with type 'datetime', converting the result to a Series (if possible).
date_cols = dataframe.select_dtypes('datetime').squeeze()

print(date_cols)
print(type(date_cols))
```

Output:

```
0   2015-01-25
1   2015-02-01
2   2015-02-08
3   2015-02-15
4   2015-02-22
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

---

#### Method 2: Selecting the column by position

Alternatively, if you know the column will never change its position (i.e. the `Dates` column will always be first), you coluld select it based on its integer-based location in the DataFrame, using [`.iloc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) rather than `.loc[]`.

When selecting only one column, the result will automatically be given as a `Series` object.

```py
# Select the first column in the DataFrame (i.e. position 0)
date_cols = dataframe.iloc[:, 0]

print(date_cols)
print(type(date_cols))
```

Output:

```
0   2015-01-25
1   2015-02-01
2   2015-02-08
3   2015-02-15
4   2015-02-22
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Comment: `dataframe.select_dtypes('datetime').squeeze()`

Comment: @sammywemmy Thank you, that's much more appropriate. I simplified my answer accordingly.